# Jquery Accordion container height problem

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I'm using JQUERY Accordion to hide/show some boxes. I have alot of content in some of these and when i click to show the heading, all the content fills out of the #mainContent - i can see this because there is a background color set to #mainContent

I assume it is a function I need to add in the inline javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            hideOnStartup: true,
            active: false,
            autoHeight: true
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion_two").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            hideOnStartup: true,
            active: false,
            autoHeight: true
        });
    });
    </script>

<div id="mainContent">

<div id="accordion">
<h4>Header</h4>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam elementum placerat. Donec scelerisque pulvinar justo, nec bibendum neque suscipit et. Phasellus consequat consequat justo, eu lacinia nibh imperdiet id. Phasellus sit amet erat quis dui hendrerit egestas. Sed dolor libero, lobortis eu varius sit amet, pretium eget nisl. Suspendisse venenatis suscipit orci blandit dignissim. Suspendisse ac tortor eleifend felis cursus tempus. Aenean sodales, quam sed aliquam placerat, ligula augue varius enim, quis ultrices mauris tellus at elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eleifend ipsum eros. Ut laoreet, ligula ut eleifend imperdiet, dolor arcu tempus velit, quis convallis urna mi ut justo. Sed egestas, lectus eget ornare congue, mauris enim condimentum erat, ut condimentum ipsum neque non purus. Etiam orci nulla, imperdiet vel tempus in, placerat id dolor. Integer convallis consequat odio. Sed ornare urna turpis, ut malesuada purus.
</div>


<div id="accordion_two">
<h4>Header Two</h4>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam elementum placerat. Donec scelerisque pulvinar justo, nec bibendum neque suscipit et. Phasellus consequat consequat justo, eu lacinia nibh imperdiet id. Phasellus sit amet erat quis dui hendrerit egestas. Sed dolor libero, lobortis eu varius sit amet, pretium eget nisl. Suspendisse venenatis suscipit orci blandit dignissim. Suspendisse ac tortor eleifend felis cursus tempus. Aenean sodales, quam sed aliquam placerat, ligula augue varius enim, quis ultrices mauris tellus at elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eleifend ipsum eros. Ut laoreet, ligula ut eleifend imperdiet, dolor arcu tempus velit, quis convallis urna mi ut justo. Sed egestas, lectus eget ornare congue, mauris enim condimentum erat, ut condimentum ipsum neque non purus. Etiam orci nulla, imperdiet vel tempus in, placerat id dolor. Integer convallis consequat odio. Sed ornare urna turpis, ut malesuada purus.
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your css look like? Make certain the containing div (ie your main content) has overflow:hidden. I usually have this layout when I use the accordion from ui

```
<div id=wrapper>
    <div class='accordion'>
      <div class='header'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Header 1</div>
      <div class='content'>Accordion content here</div>
      <div class='header'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Header 2</div>
      <div class='content'>Accordion content here</div> 
    </div>
   </div>

   //css
   #wrapper{overflow:hidden;}
```

Set up a height and width on the wrapper and accordion and you should be set.

Comment: I think it works now, just have to figure out why there a  gap appearing at the bottom of the collapsed divs. Thanks!

Comment: I am using curveycorners.js to round the edges of my DIV for the maincontent but for some reason when i have it set to the #maincontent and i collapse the divs that are using accordion all of the containing content disappears I assume its to do with using overflow: hidden what would you recommend I do?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with curveycorners.js as I usually use the sliding door css technique for corners(mainly because most of the time any js changes to content will show as a flicker onload in IE). You might be able to get away with overflow:auto (in IE the accordion might flicker outside of the containing element when you open a new section). Sorry I'm not going to be much help on that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is a little wrong.  The part to be collapsed needs to be in an inner div like this:

```
<div id="mainContent">

  <div id="accordion">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <div>
      Lorem ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="accordion_two">
    <h4>Header Two</h4>
    <div>
      Lorem ...
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also, you don't need two accordions for this.  You can do:

```
<div id="mainContent">

  <div id="accordion">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <div>
      Lorem ...
    </div>

    <h4>Header Two</h4>
    <div>
      Lorem ...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMH/S4Qfx/

Comment: I just checked my actual HTML and all the parts that need to be collapsed are contained in inner divs but it still overlaps #mainContent could this be an issue with the javascript?